# MS Access get top 2 rows from table when grouped and ordered

Tags: sql, ms-access

In Microsoft Access, I have a table of medical procedures and I'd like to be able to use a select query to group the procedures by doctor (i.e. which doctor has carried the procedure out the most) but limiting only to 2 doctors per procedure.

My data table is structured as such:

```
| CLINICAL_ID | CLINICAL_DESC     | DOCTOR | PRICE   | COST   |
|-------------|-------------------|--------|---------|--------|
| PROCEDURE1  | Hip Replacement   | X01    | 10000   | 8000   |
| PROCEDURE1  | Hip Replacement   | X01    | 10000   | 8500   |
| PROCEDURE1  | Hip Replacement   | X01    | 10000   | 8300   |
| PROCEDURE1  | Hip Replacement   | X01    | 10000   | 7200   |
| PROCEDURE1  | Hip Replacement   | X02    | 10000   | 8100   |
| PROCEDURE1  | Hip Replacement   | X03    | 10000   | 11000  |
| PROCEDURE1  | Hip Replacement   | X03    | 10000   | 9800   |
| PROCEDURE1  | Hip Replacement   | X04    | 10000   | 8000   |
| PROCEDURE2  | Hip Revision      | X01    | 14000   | 12500  |
| PROCEDURE2  | Hip Revision      | X02    | 14000   | 11000  |
| PROCEDURE2  | Hip Revision      | X03    | 14000   | 13000  |
| PROCEDURE2  | Hip Revision      | X03    | 14000   | 13000  |
| PROCEDURE2  | Hip Revision      | X03    | 14000   | 11000  |
| PROCEDURE2  | Hip Revision      | X04    | 14000   | 11000  |
| PROCEDURE2  | Hip Revision      | X04    | 14000   | 14500  |
| PROCEDURE2  | Hip Revision      | X04    | 14000   | 13000  |
```

and I'd like the results to look like:

```
| CLINICAL_ID | CLINICAL_DESC     | DOCTOR | COUNT | AVG_PRICE | AVG_COST |
|-------------|-------------------|--------|-------|-----------|----------|
| PROCEDURE1  | Hip Replacement   | X01    | 4     | 10000     | 8000     |
| PROCEDURE1  | Hip Replacement   | X03    | 2     | 10000     | 10400    |
| PROCEDURE2  | Hip Replacement   | X04    | 3     | 14000     | 12833    |
| PROCEDURE2  | Hip Replacement   | X03    | 3     | 14000     | 12333    |
```

My query so far, which seems to just show all of the doctors looks like:

```
SELECT
  Clinical_id,
  Clinical_desc,
  Doctor,
  COUNT(Doctor) AS Count,
  AVG(Price) AS Avg_price,
  AVG(Cost) AS Avg_cost
FROM (SELECT
  Clinical_id,
  Clinical_desc,
  Doctor,
  Price,
  Cost
FROM Summary_Data t
WHERE Doctor IN (SELECT TOP 2
  Doctor
FROM Summary_Data
WHERE Doctor = t.Doctor
GROUP BY Doctor
ORDER BY COUNT(Doctor) DESC, SUM(Cost) DESC
)) q
GROUP BY Clinical_id, Clinical_desc, Doctor
ORDER BY COUNT(Doctor) DESC, SUM(Cost) DESC;
```

It appears the `Top 2` element is not working but I cannot, for the life of me, workout what else I need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the subquery, but I think your query should work.

Here is a somewhat simpler version:

```
SELECT Clinical_id, Clinical_desc, Doctor,
       COUNT(Doctor) AS Count,
       AVG(Price) AS Avg_price,
       AVG(Cost) AS Avg_cost
FROM Summary_Data as sd
WHERE sd.Doctor IN (SELECT TOP 2 sd2.Doctor
                    FROM Summary_Data as sd2
                    WHERE sd2.Clinical_id = sd.Clinical_id
                    GROUP BY sd2.Doctor
                    ORDER BY COUNT(sd2.Doctor) DESC, SUM(sd2.Cost) DESC,
                             sd2.Doctor  -- Just added to keep the ordering unique so 2 rows are always returned
                   )
GROUP BY sd.Clinical_id, sd.Clinical_desc, sd.Doctor
ORDER BY COUNT(Doctor) DESC, SUM(Cost) DESC;
```

Comment: Simplification is a +1 but for some reason it does not sort the rows. I get the full dataset returned.

Comment: The `Top 2` query works by itself when I test (removing the WHERE clause) but collectively, it doesn't.

Comment: @BarryBlade . . . The correlation clause used the wrong column.

Comment: unfortunately makes no difference. Still returns all the rows as opposed to the top 2.

Comment: This should be returning two doctors for each clinic.  I don't see how it could not be doing that.  Are you sure the `WHERE` clause is correct when you run it?  Or, because this is MS Access, the subquery could be returning more than 2 doctors when there are ties -- so the `ORDER BY` is important.

Comment: you were right! Apologies my `clinical_id` field became autoincrementing in a modification process. Top stuff

Answer (score 0):

Consider a correlated count subquery to calculate a row count that you can then filter for top 2 rankings. First, save below aggregate query as its own stored query (to avoid the heavy nesting in main query which is still doable):

**Aggregate** Query *(referenced below as ClinicalDoctorAgg)*

```
SELECT Clinical_id, Clinical_desc, Doctor, AVG(Price) AS Avg_Price,
       Round(AVG(Cost),0) AS Avg_Cost, Count(*) AS Count_Procedures
FROM Summary_Data
GROUP BY Clinical_id, Clinical_desc, Doctor;
```

**Final** Query *(can modify for top ## using `WHERE` clause)*

```
SELECT main.*
FROM 
 (SELECT agg.*, (SELECT Count(*) 
                 FROM ClinicalDoctorAgg sub 
                 WHERE sub.Count_Procedures >= agg.Count_Procedures 
                 AND sub.Clinical_id = agg.Clinical_id 
                 AND sub.Clinical_desc = agg.Clinical_desc) As RowCount
  FROM ClinicalDoctorAgg As agg)  AS main
WHERE main.RowCount <= 2;
```

Comment: The same issue as @GordonLinoff it only seems to return the full 16 rows. Nice use of aggregate queries though.

Comment: Interesting! On my end, this produced exactly your desired result from posted data. Did you run both source and final queries? First one has to be saved.

Comment: you were right! Apologies my `clinical_id` field became autoincrementing in a modification process.